# how do I do two way data binding on for each loop columns in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a `foreach` loop in a table that consist of multiple rows like this:

```
<td class="p-3 px-5">
    <input type="text"
        wire:model="email"
        value="{{$row->email}}"
        class="bg-transparent" >
</td>
```

Which gets data from:

```
$data = Teamuser::join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
    ->get([
        'users.name as username',
        'teams.name',
        'users.email',
        'team_user.role',
        'team_user.id',
        'team_user.user_id'
    ]);

return view('livewire.editusers',compact('data'));
```

I'm trying to use `wire:model` into a button to update data, the `value` doesnt works anymore. I need to do a two way data binding with something like this to insert data in my foreach's column.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = Teamuser::findOrFail($id);
    $real = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    $third = Team::findOrFail($team_id);
    $this->username = $real->name;
    $this->email = $real->email;
    $this->team = $third->name;
    $this->role = $user->role;
}
```

but since there are multiple $id in `foreach` table, how do I insert all the datas in the for each column?

[image: The view is something like this]

```
@foreach($data as $row)
  @php 
    App\Http\Livewire\Teamusers::edit($row->id,$row->user_id,$row-team_id);
  @endphp

{{--call edit() function from teamusers component--}}


  <td class="p-3 px-5">
    <input type="text" wire:model="username" class="bg-transparent">
  </td>
  <td class="p-3 px-5">
    <input type="text" wire:model="email" value="{{$row->email}}" class="bg-transparent" >
  </td>
@endforeach
```

Edit:

I solved the binding problem by importing multiple models, but now it works like this.

[image]

I think its because the php code in the for each loop. But where else could i place it aside from there?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried binding edit($id) to a button ```<button wire:click="edit('{{ $fieldequip->Identification_No }}')" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Edit</button>``` and the details of the particular $id in another ```create``` view. It works but i couldn't make it to display the details from all the $id's from the database.

Comment: Can you add the html you’re using in your question please?

Comment: I added some details in edit() and the new line, I hope it gives more insight to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to your data incorrectly, you need to bind to a specific iteration within your `$data`.

I don't have your database or dataset, so I have replicated a simplified example below using the default `User` model.

**Livewire Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class ModelIterator extends Component
{
    public $users;

    protected $rules = [
        'users.*.email' => ['required']
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->users = User::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.model-iterator');
    }

    public function save($id)
    {
        $user = $this->users->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

**Livewire Component View**

```
<div>
    @foreach ($users as $index => $user)
        <div wire:key="user-field-{{ $user->id }}">
            // Note the difference in how wire:model is defined here
            <input type="text" wire:model="users.{{ $index }}.email" />
            <button type="button" wire:click="save({{ $user->id }})">Save</button>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I should have do it like this, thanks for the answer!